# How can we set a flag in kuberneties?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, amazon-eks

The requirement is we want to create a new yaml file where we need to set a flag as True/false and file should not get executed when it is false and it should get executed when it is true. Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: How would you do it without using Kubernetes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.